# Different home page for every customer

Tags: magento-1.8, cms, static-block, home

Hi I have a question is it possible to make a one static block to get different content for every customer that is logged in. And with this to get different home page for the customers.

Comment: I might say that this is a nice idea for a community extension. It could really improve the customer experience, but it may create issues if you have a full page cache system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting idea.
If I would implement something like this, I would do it like this.
Let's start with the different homepage.
The action that renders the homepage is `Mage_Cms_IndexController::indexAction`.
By default it looks like this:

```
public function indexAction($coreRoute = null)
{
    $pageId = Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Cms_Helper_Page::XML_PATH_HOME_PAGE);
    if (!Mage::helper('cms/page')->renderPage($this, $pageId)) {
        $this->_forward('defaultIndex');
    }
}
```

This means that magento gets the page you set as homepage in system->configuration, and renders is.
If there is no such page it fallbacks to a default page.

I would rewrite this action and put my logic for it.  Of course there is the problem of managing these homepages. But that's up to you.

As for blocks it should be simpler.
Just create one static block with this content:

```
{{block type="core/template" template="path/to/template.phtml"}}
```

and you can put your logic in `path/to/template.phtml` where you can access the current customer like this :

```
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure it is possible.

put an phtml on the page content using this sintax

```
{{block type="core/template" template="page/home_content.phtml"}}
```

inside this home_content.phtml put this code

```
if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
if($customer->isMyFriend()) //Check some data into customer 
    echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('cms_block_id_friend')->toHtml();
else
    echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('cms_block_id_foe')->toHtml();
}
else
    echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('cms_block_not_logged_in')->toHtml();
```

of course this is just a skeleton but should be sufficient to put you in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with customer groups and show a different block according to the group the customer is in.
You will have to code this by yourself since i did not see any extensions to achieve this.